# Simple Concurrency

Tags: go, concurrency

Can someone explain how this works:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func say(s string) {
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
        fmt.Println(s)
    }
}

func main() {
    say("world")
}
```

But this doesnt work once i add the word go to the routine in main

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func say(s string) {
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
        fmt.Println(s)
    }
}

func main() {
    go say("world")
}
```

I think its because its finishing before executing the goroutine.

Comment: Correct. As soon as `main` returns, the program exits, regardless of any other goroutines that may be running.

Comment: so we'd have to implement a waitGroup correct?

Comment: That depends on your actual use case. In this example case you just wouldn't run it in a goroutine because there's no reason to.

Comment: i see. thanks for the assistance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "world" goroutine does not run or complete because main returns and the program exits.

> When that function invocation returns, the program exits. It does not wait for other (non-main) goroutines to complete.
>    https://golang.org/ref/spec#Program_execution